# After Jquery success call, need to click event automatically

Tags: jquery, ajax, click

In the below code, after success need to bind the click and should fire the event in the first click only.

```
$(this).click(function(){
   var $obj = $(this);
   var urlLink = someURL;
   var data = "id=" + "123";
   $.ajax({
        url : urlLink,
    data : data,
    cache: false,
    success : function(resp) {
      $obj.bind("click",eval(someFunction)); //This someFunction will call another function.
    }
   });
});
```

Please let me know how to fire two events like this in one click.
Right now, to execute i need to click twice.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This looks like a very weird thing to do, and could potentially end up in endless recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is failing before the trigger, because the variable `event` is not defined, your function crashes at the line `event.stopPropagation()`. Also, try to get rid of `eval` in the event binding, what exactly is `TRTP.showSourceToolTip`?

If it's a function, you can just do the following:

```
success : function(resp) {
    // Bind the click event to a function
    $obj.click(TRTP.showSourceToolTip);

    // This will call the function in the context of the object's DOM element
    TRTP.showSourceToolTip.apply($obj[0]);
}
```

**Update:**

The problem with the updated code is that you will just keep binding click events. If you bind and event in jQuery, it won't replace the original, but both actions will fire in order. You might want to `unbind()` your ajax handler once there is a proper response.

The code below will actually unbind the ajax handler right after the request will fire to avoid repeated clicks before the response. Once the ajax is successful, it will bind a different handler, and triggers its click. If the ajax fails, it will bind the ajax handler back so the user can try again.

```
function ajaxHandler(){
    var $obj = $(this);
    var urlLink = someURL;
    var data = "id=" + "123";

    // Unbind the ajax handler to prevent re-fire before ajax request completes
    $obj.unbind("click", ajaxHandler);

    $.ajax({
        url: urlLink,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(resp){
            // Bind the new event handler
            // Removed eval from the bind, put it back if you desperately need it
            $obj.bind("click", someFunction);

            // Fire click on Object
            $obj.click();
        },
        error: function(){
            // Put the ajax handler back so the user can try again if it fails
            $obj.bind("click", ajaxHandler);
        }
    });
}

// This is where you first bind the ajax handler
// I'm not sure what scope you're in, make sure this references the desired object.
$(this).click(ajaxHandler);
```

Comment: I tried removing the event and also updated the code in question, please check. Still not able to solve

Comment: It's a bit dangerous to do it like that, do you want `someFunction` to completely replace your current click handler after the ajax completes?

Comment: @Max your new update is even more confusing. Your naming it `someFunction` -- if it's a function then call it as a function. However, if it's a function string then it makes more sense to eval, but again it really depends on what's inside that string.

Comment: that "someFunction" will call some jquery functions internally and will give the tooltip. This will not hit to server.

Comment: Let me get things straight... `someFunction` displays a tooltip, and you want to pass the ajax response text to that function. But you only want to read the tooltip's text on the first click via ajax, subsequent clicks will just call `someFunction` with the saved value. Is that somewhat close to what you want?

Comment: ok, let me be more specific.. $obj.attr("name", "aaaaaaaaa").bind(click, someFunction);

Comment: I will pass this name to that "someFunction" and will display tooltip. everything is fine now.. Only thing is once I click "$(this).click(function(){" after ajax call success "someFunction" within the $obj should fire.

Comment: Thanks Darth, This is what i am looking for. I understood where things are going wrong. I need to unbind first.

Answer (score 0):

if your handler is well defined, try:

```
$obj.click();
```

but looking in your code, I think I would rewrite it completely...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you dynamically getting tooltip text and want to show it once the ajax request is successful. Why not just:

```
success : function(resp) {
   eval(TRTP.showSourceToolTip);

  // Or:
  TRTP.showSourceToolTip(resp);
}
```

What is TRTP.showSourceToolTip? It looks like a function anyway, so no need for eval.

Comment: I should not call the function explicitly. It actually defines a tooltip to that object.